# How to avoid flipping health bar in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a platformer game in unity, but I have a weeny problem, my camera is flipping. This causes flipping of every object, I attach to player (healthbar for instance), how to avoid this flipping?

Comment: need more info and code snippets

Answer (score 1):

Im not really sure on what u are trying to do. But if i understand you correctly, try freezing the Z Axis on whatever is flipping

Answer (score 0):

Oh I know what you want. So you just have to clamp the value of the health bar.
I'll show you an example with just the a float because I don't know what your code looks like.

```
float health = 100f;

void Update(){
     health = Mathf.Clamp(health, 0f, 100f);
}
```

Your value can't get lower than the second input, and can't go higher than your third input.

[EDIT] By the way. You better include code. Maybe the code that edits the health bar. Because you are not likely to get a good answer if you don't